# I'm using angular material matInput matFormfield and matselect, but it doesn't show it on the screen

Tags: angular, angular-material

First I was adding the mat components manually and at first, it was working, but then I used Bard to write the rest of the code according to a pattern I've given, and then I just started copying and pasting the content and all of a sudden it stopped loading the components properly, even the one I've done manually.

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 m-3">
                    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                        <mat-label>Nome do Projeto:</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="projeto.nome" type="text" name="nome" required>
                        <mat-error>O Campo é obrigatório</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Descrição</mat-label>
                        <textarea [(ngModel)]="projeto.descricao" matInput
                                cdkTextareaAutosize
                                #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                                cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
                                cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5" name="descricao"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 w-100">
                        <div class="row">
                            
                            
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                                    <mat-label>Nome do Projeto:</mat-label>
                                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="projeto.progresso" name="progresso"
                                                placeholder="Exemplo: 50%" required>
                                    <mat-error>O Campo é obrigatório</mat-error>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-label>Estado</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="projeto.estado" name="estado">
                                        <mat-option value="Pedido">Pedido</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option value="Em Progresso">Em Progresso</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option value="Feito">Feito</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 w-100">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-label>Data de Início</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="projeto.data_inicio" name="data_inicio">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-label>Data Fim Prevista</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="projeto.data_fim_prevista" name="data_fim_prevista">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-label>Tipo Projeto</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="projeto.tipo_projeto" name="tipo_projeto">
                                        <mat-option value="Interno">Interno</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option value="Externo">Externo</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-label>Cliente</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="projeto.id_cliente" name="id_cliente">
                                        <mat-option [value]="5">Localhost</mat-option>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let cliente of clientes" [value]="cliente.id_cliente">
                                        {{ cliente.nome }}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                                    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                                        <mat-label>Sumário:</mat-label>
                                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="projeto.sumario" name="sumario" required>
                                        <mat-error>O Campo é obrigatório</mat-error>
                                        </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="meu-botao" [disabled]="isCreating" (click)="criarProjeto()">
            {{ isCreating ? 'Aguarde...' : 'Gravar' }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what the page is looking like now: [what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr9Dd.png)
this is what it should look like (I took a screenshot from another component):

I've tried removing the code and placing it back but nothing, this is something only happening in this component, in components the mat input shows normally

Comment: please add your console log.

Comment: ►ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a
MatFormFieldControl.
core.mjs:8506
at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.mjs:430:12) MatFormField._assertFormFieldControl (form-field.mjs:705:19)
at
at MatFormField.ngAfter ContentChecked at callHook (core.mjs:2498:18)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2457:17)
at
(form-field.mjs:613:14)
executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2408:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10460:21)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11480:13)
at
refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10210:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10469:13)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, I think that you did not import MatInputModule.

add this where you prefer.

```
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
```

Update:

Another possible reason is some of your inputs don't have matInput directive. in your case this is the reason.

Comment: I already have it imported in the modules

Comment: i updated my answer. some of your inputs don't have matInput directive.